# ccny_openni_launch fail

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use ccny_rgbd_tools , I compiled the tools from the source , the output :

roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publsh_cloud:=true

> openni.launch publsh_cloud:=true ...
> logging to
> /root/.ros/log/acd627fc-5cee-11e3-bef9-c8a030b6727e/roslaunch-ubuntu-armhf-1174.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://ubuntu-armhf:45387/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  *
> /openni_driver/depth_camera_info_url
>
> - /openni_driver/depth_frame_id  * /openni_driver/depth_mode  *
>   /openni_driver/device_id  *
>   /openni_driver/image_mode  *
>   /openni_driver/rgb_camera_info_url  *
>   /openni_driver/rgb_frame_id  *
>   /rgbd_image_proc/calib_path  *
>   /rgbd_image_proc/publish_cloud  *
>   /rgbd_image_proc/scale  *
>   /rgbd_image_proc/unwarp  *
>   /rgbd_image_proc/verbose  * /rosdistro
> - /rosversion
>
> NODES   /
> camera_rgb_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
> camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
> debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
> openni_driver (nodelet/nodelet)
> rgbd_image_proc (nodelet/nodelet)
> rgbd_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[rgbd_manager-1]: started with
> pid [1192] [ INFO]
> [1386166814.932014355]: Initializing
> nodelet with 1 worker threads.
> process[openni_driver-2]: started with
> pid [1214] [ INFO]
> [1386166818.151105481]: Loading
> nodelet /openni_driver of type
> openni_camera/driver to manager
> rgbd_manager with the following
> remappings: [ INFO]
> [1386166818.168595981]: /depth ->
> /camera/depth [ INFO]
> [1386166818.182154397]: /ir ->
> /camera/ir [ INFO]
> [1386166818.190459147]: /rgb ->
> /camera/rgb [ INFO]
> [1386166821.764989731]: Number devices
> connected: 1 [ INFO]
> [1386166822.137412189]: 1. device on
> bus 001:04 is a SensorV2 (601) from
> PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id
> '1301040309' [ INFO]
> [1386166822.158497814]: Searching for
> device with index = 1 [ INFO]
> [1386166822.586708023]: No matching
> device found.... waiting for devices.
> Reason:
> openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&,
> const xn::NodeInfo&, const
> xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&,
> const xn::NodeInfo&) @
> /root/catkin_ws/src/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp
> @ 65 : creating image generator
> failed. Reason: Failed to set USB
> interface! process[debayer-3]: started
> with pid [1251] [ INFO]
> [1386166825.679466898]: Number devices
> connected: 1 [ INFO]
> [1386166825.688282565]: 1. device on
> bus 001:04 is a SensorV2 (601) from
> PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id
> '1301040309' [ INFO]
> [1386166825.708856357]: Searching for
> device with index = 1 [ INFO]
> [1386166825.748079148]: Opened
> 'SensorV2' on bus 1:4 with serial
> number '1301040309' [ERROR]
> [1386166826.468534148]: Failed to load
> nodelet [/debayer] of type
> [image_proc/debayer]: According to the
> loaded plugin descriptions the class
> image_proc/debayer with base class
> type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist.
> Declared types are
> ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet
> openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader
> pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/NodeletDEMUX
> pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/PCDReader
> pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough
> pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer
> pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer
> pcl/ProjectInliers
> pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval
> pcl/VoxelGrid test_nodelet/ConsoleTest
> test_nodelet/Plus
> test_nodelet_topic_tools/NodeletThrottleString
> [FATAL] [1386166826.486667607]:
> Service call failed! [debayer-3]
> process has died [pid 1251, exit code
> 255, cmd
> /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/nodelet/nodelet
> load image_proc/debayer rgbd_manager
> image_raw:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
> image_color:=/camera/rgb/image_color
> __name:=debayer __log:=/root/.ros/log/acd627fc-5cee-11e3-bef9-c8a030b6727e/debayer-3.log].
> log file:
> /root/.ros/log/acd627fc-5cee-11e3-bef9-c8a030b6727e/debayer-3*.log process[rgbd_image_proc-4]: started
> with pid [1321] [ INFO]
> [1386166830.955137816]: rgb_frame_id =
> '/camera_rgb_optical_frame'  [ INFO]
> [1386166830.964522691]: depth_frame_id
> = '/camera_depth_optical_frame'  [ WARN] [1386166831.168540649]:
> [rgb_1301040309] does not match name
> rgb in file
> /root/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd_data/calibration_openni_default/rgb.yml
> [ WARN] [1386166831.219288024]:
> [depth_1301040309] does not match name
> depth in file
> /root/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd_data/calibration_openni_default/depth.yml
> [ERROR] [1386166833.444105024]: Failed
> to load nodelet [/rgbd_image_proc] of
> type [ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet]:
> Failed to load library
> /root/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/lib/librgbd_image_proc_nodelet.so.
> Make sure that you are calling the
> PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the
> library code, and that names are
> consistent between this macro and your
> XML. Error string: Could not load
> library (Poco exception =
> libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or
> directory) [FATAL]
> [1386166833.466222482]: Service call
> failed! [rgbd_image_proc-4] process
> has died [pid 1321, exit code 255, cmd
> /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/nodelet/nodelet
> load ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet
> rgbd_manager __name:=rgbd_image_proc
> __log:=/root/.ros/log/acd627fc-5cee-11e3-bef9-c8a030b6727e/rgbd_image_proc-4.log].
> log file:
> /root/.ros/log/acd627fc-5cee-11e3-bef9-c8a030b6727e/rgbd_image_proc-4*.log
> process[camera_rgb_frame_tf-5]:
> started with pid [1370]
> process[camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf-6]:
> started with pid [1381]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106926/ccny_openni_launch-fail/) by [7mdan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/9371/7mdan92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-26**:
That output is unreadable. Please use 4 spaces to indent code, or use the "preformatted text" button ("101010") when editing your answer. Unfortunately, the line breaks are messed up, otherwise I'd do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the opencv libraries are not supported. I would ask you to download the ccny_rgbd_tools from this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95042389/ccny_rgbd_tools.zip

This should work on ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte with rosbuild system.

1. Remove the libg2o libraries from ubuntu software center
2. rosdep install ccny_rgbd_tools
   then rosmake and hope fully it will work

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-26**:
I wouldn't recommend using some zip file. It's a git repo for a reason, so better figure out what branch / commit works for what setup. If we don't keep code in *one* place, things will just start to get chaotic.